Ubuntu 24.04; how to use xinput to swap the touchscreen in Y-axis
It isn't quite clear to me how the xinput coordinate transformation works.
With this command (identity matrix), the touch screen will respond, but the Y-axis is inverted:
xinput set-prop "eGalaxTouch Virtual Device for Single" "Coordinate Transformation Matrix" 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1
This answer has some sample inputs; it appears that the last line is always 0 0 1, as per What "Coordinate Transformation Matrix" must I use to get my touchscreen working correctly?
What would the matrix be for inverting the Y axis?
(X is left right, Y is up down)
